# Formik custom file upload gives InvalidStateError

Tags: react-bootstrap, formik, yup, react-state

I'm using react-bootstrap custom file upload. Want to validate, that input is not empty and type of the file is video. Using `react-bootstrap` custom file upload it doesnt give me any error message on empty form. With the basic one it does. When i upload some it gives me `InvalidStateError: The object is in an invalid state.` Here it is in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-saha-0b2dv?file=/src/App.js). The commented lines are for the basic file input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is related to the `value` prop of `Form.File`, you can't render a `File`.
If you change it to: `value={values.file?.filename || ""}` it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thank you! @CD.. You know why it doesn't show the error message, even though it is set correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can add `feedback={errors.file}` to the `Form.File` component instead.